ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList while run mvn test
I Write a benchmark tests and put in src/test folder. Code:
public class BenchMarkTest {
    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class BenchmarkState {
        ...
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void singleThread(BenchmarkState state) {
        ...
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void executorService(BenchmarkState state) {
        ...
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void forkJointPool(BenchmarkState state) {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void launchBenchmark() throws Exception {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(this.getClass().getName() + ".*")
            .mode(Mode.AverageTime)
            .timeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
            .warmupIterations(1)
            .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
            .measurementIterations(1)
            .threads(3)
            .forks(1)
            .shouldFailOnError(true)
            .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }
}

So it runs normally when I call launchBenchmark via Intellij IDEA Run Configuration.
But it fails when I try to run "mvn test" after "mvn clean" with error:
ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList

You should use mvn package instead...

@khmarbaise, using mvn package I get same result

Do you have an example project on github or alike?

The solution is add specific path to :
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>${java.release}</release>
                        <parameters>true</parameters>
                        <proc>full</proc>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                            </path>
                            <!--add this path-->
                            <path>
                                <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
                                <version>1.35</version>
                            </path>
                            <!---->
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
